# Errors setting up Ruby development environment: nodejs not found, could not connect to server

Tags: node.js, ruby, development-environment

I'm a new developer-in-training attempting to set up my Ruby development environment on a Windows machine using Ubuntu. I'm following the instructions here:

https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10

I've made it to the last few steps of the process, which is where I'm started to get errors:

```
# Navigate to the C: drive on Windows. Do this every time you open the Linux console.
cd /mnt/c

# Create a code directory at C:\code for your Rails apps to live (You only need to do this once)
mkdir -p code

#### If you want to use Postgres
# Note that this will expect a postgres user with the same username
# as your app, you may need to edit config/database.yml to match the
# user you created earlier
rails new myapp -d postgresql

#### or if you want to use SQLite (not recommended)
# rails new myapp

#### Or if you want to use MySQL
# rails new myapp -d mysql

# Then, move into the application directory
cd myapp

# If you setup MySQL or Postgres with a username/password, modify the
# config/database.yml file to contain the username/password that you specified

# Create the database
rake db:create

rails server
```

On the step to set up Postgres:

```
 rails new myapp -d postgresql
```

I receive this error about setting up nodejs:

```
/home/event/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:53: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/event/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5 in PATH, mode 040777
sh: 1: node: not found
sh: 1: nodejs: not found
Node.js not installed. Please download and install Node.js https://nodejs.org/en/download/
```

Even after I go to the URL provided and install NodeJS, that error still shows up when I attempt to repeat the process. Is this just a matter of it not existing in the correct path and I need to relocate it?

Also, I've attempted to proceed with the other steps despite that error. When I enter this command, the second last one in the article referenced above:

```
rake db:create
```

I receive this error:

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
Couldn't create 'myapp_development' database. Please check your configuration.
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?


Caused by:
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Tasks: TOP => db:create
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I've searched around about this with little success, and attempted to decipher what the error messages mean; but at my current level of knowledge it just seems beyond me. Appreciate any insight anyone has to share on this!

Comment: It clearly says ur node is not installed. On the tutorial link of gorails, there is a command to installed node.

curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

Have you done this?

Comment: Yes, I went back through the instructions once more time and I'm no longer receiving the area about have nodejs installed, so that part's sorted.

Unfortunately I'm still receiving the error about being unable to connect to the server/database.

Comment: make sure the username and password passed on database.yml file are correct.